# Problem with cache in template

Tags: theming, caching

In the hook_preprocess_page i'm sending at twig template the value of one cookie, but always have the value of the first time of loading page.

```
function supertics_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.query_args';
    $variables['utm_medium'] = $_COOKIE['utm_medium'];
}
```

It's possible avoid this cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yep in this case cache depends of the query args, wich means once some url query args are met a cache is bind. Then it won't change any more. This is usefull fore search pages for examples: `/search?type=article&status=published`
You should try with `$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'cookie:utm_medium';`
Or if it still doesn't work with session or user contexts...
hope it helps,